# Não consigo inserir no BD com entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Esse é meu código de inserção. Porque dá erro? O que devo fazer?

```
public int abreOsParceiro(string os, string cnpj, string dataAbertura, string dataVisita, string tecnico)
        {
             WEBEntities db = new WEBEntities();
            PDVOsParceiro pdv = new PDVOsParceiro();
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                pdv.CNPJ = cnpj;
                pdv.DataAberturaOs = Convert.ToDateTime(dataAbertura);
                pdv.DataVisita = Convert.ToDateTime(dataVisita);
                pdv.Tecnico = tecnico;
                pdv.OS = Convert.ToInt32(os);

                db.T_OsParceiro.Add(pdv);==>> Aqui dá o erro
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Esse é o erro:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<V99SuporteTecnico.Models.T_OsParceiro>.Add(V99SuporteTecnico.Models.T_OsParceiro)' has some invalid arguments
```

Quais os argumentos inválidos?

Minha classe está ssim:

```
[Table(Name = "T_TarefaParceiro")]
    public class PDVOsParceiro
    {
        [Column]
        [DataMember]
        public int IDTarefaParceiro { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [DataMember]
        public int OS { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime DataAberturaOs { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [DataMember]
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }
...............
```

É isso mesmo ou não?

Comment: Precisaria conhecer sua classe que declara o que é o membro `T_OsParceiro` de `db` e verificar o que o método `Add` está esperando. Existe lá algum método que espera um tipo `PDVOsParceiro`? Se não existe, ou precisa criar ou ver se pode passar um elemento de outro tipo ou ainda ver se é possível fazer um *cast* para o tipo esperado, o que me parece pouco provável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem diz tudo.

O contexto espera um `T_OsParceiro`. Você está passando um `PDVOsParceiro`. O correto seria:

```
    public int abreOsParceiro(string os, string cnpj, string dataAbertura, string dataVisita, string tecnico)
    {
         WEBEntities db = new WEBEntities();
        T_OsParceiropdv = new T_OsParceiro();
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            /* Aqui não sei se o tipo T_OsParceiro tem os mesmos campos de PDVOsParceiro, mas a ideia é que ele seja preenchido neste ponto */

            db.T_OsParceiro.Add(pdv);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```